# How to call set value through ajax response from inline script in html?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I set value of my input type hidden in ajax response and then I wanna display my page with set content.

Ajax :

```
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data);
 $("#hiddenSearchedTextValue").val(JSONObject[1]);

 window.location = JSONObject[0]; // redirect on my page
```

on My page, where I wanna display my set value:

```
    <script>
        var value = "";
        window.onload = function () {
            $ = jQuery;

            value = $("#hiddenSearchedTextValue").val();
        }
    </script>

 <div class="container">
        <h1> Searched for: <script>document.write(value)</script></h1>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenSearchedTextValue" value="">
```

Now it returns nothing. Anyone have some advice for me, please? I tried to read something about global scope, but nothing helped. Thank you

Comment: `value` is only assigned a value _after_ it is referenced (in `write(value)`). Also, don't use write() for this. Update the DOM instead.

Comment: I think you can set the value only after you have navigated to the page

Comment: @marekful please can you submit some example code? I will be so thankful

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding from your code snippets you are getting a response from Ajax and then redirecting the page?  If this is the case then you loose your value when the page is re-loaded i.e. once you have your response.

I think you need to pass the value as a parameter in your url, then set it on page load

I think you want to just update the value and then reset the input, something like (in PHP):

```
value = $("#hiddenSearchedTextValue").val();
```

.....

....

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSearchedTextValue" value="' . $_GET['searchString'] . '">
```

(with some appropriate security checking etc).  Although you might as well just do this in the h1 tag.  Maybe seeing some more of your code and your Ajax would make it easier to understand how you think it should work

Comment: you know, I can not set value to my URL, due to pagination...  so what you think with $_GET['searchString']. please can you post all code example according to my ?